# PHP strpos check against many

Tags: php, strpos

I am looking to use `strpos` to check for many chars in a string, for example:

I would like to separately check for the chars `:`,`!`, and `&` in $string. If any of them are found at any point, return false.

What's the most efficient way to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
preg_match("/[:!&]/", $string) !== 1;
```

Example:

```
var_dump(preg_match("/[:!&]/", "this is !a test string"));
> int(1)
var_dump(preg_match("/[:!&]/", "this is a test string"));
> int(0)
```

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

> If any of them are found, return false.

Since you don't care about the actual position of the character, you could use regex:

```
preg_match("/[:!&]/", $str); // 1 if found, 0 if none found
```

Answer (score 1):

If your post is accurate and what you are trying to do is return FALSE if those strings are found, `strpos()` is not the right function. `strpos()` is to find where in a string certain characters (or strings) first appear.

If your stated goal is accurate, you probably want something more like this:

```
if( preg_match( "/[\:\!&]/", $str ) > 0 ) { return false; }
```

Comment: There is no need for escaping those characters when they are in a character class.

Comment: Gotcha. I just commented on your post, then deleted my comment. As a matter of practice, I always escape characters that are defined as 'special characters' by `preg_quote()` [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)